# Faulty Pandas dataframe read_json sorting on python3.5.9

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe with more than 10 rows is incorrectly sorted on python3.5.9 after converting to json and back to pandas.DataFrame.

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_json

columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
data = [[1*i, 2*i, 3*i] for i in range(11)]
df = DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)
print(df)
#      a   b   c
# 0    0   0   0
# 1    1   2   3
# 2    2   4   6
# 3    3   6   9
# 4    4   8  12
# 5    5  10  15
# 6    6  12  18
# 7    7  14  21
# 8    8  16  24
# 9    9  18  27
# 10  10  20  30

new_df = read_json(df.to_json())
print(new_df)
#      a   b   c
# 0    0   0   0
# 1    1   2   3
# 10  10  20  30   # this should be the last line
# 2    2   4   6
# 3    3   6   9
# 4    4   8  12
# 5    5  10  15
# 6    6  12  18
# 7    7  14  21
# 8    8  16  24
# 9    9  18  27
```

So DataFrame which was created with `read_json` seems to be sorting indexes like strings (1,10,2,3,...) instead of ints (1,2,3..).

Behaviour generated with Python 3.5.9 (default, Jan  4 2020, 04:09:01) (docker image [python:3.5-stretch](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/d2a2b4f7422aac78c7d5ea6aadc49d009d184a5f/3.5/stretch/Dockerfile))

Everything seems to be working fine on my local machine (Python 3.8.1 (default, Dec 21 2019, 20:57:38)).

pandas==0.25.3 was used on both instances.

Is where a way to fix this without upgrading python?

Comment: its just a version thing.. in 3.6 and on it is working fine.. can you try printing the dtype of the two dataframes.

Comment: df.index == RangeIndex(start=0, stop=11, step=1)
new_df.index == Int64Index([0, 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')

As per python version, true, problem is - I can't easily upgrade the version on the environment in which i want to solve this problem

Comment: try sort_index()

Comment: sort_index fixes it to expected. Any idea why the different sorting is different between 3.5 and 3.8?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort_values` to sort the dataframe on the column `a`. Something like below:

```
new_df = read_json(df.to_json())

#sort column
print(new_df.sort_values('a'))

#sort index
print(new_df.sort_index())

#ouput
     a   b   c
0    0   0   0
1    1   2   3
2    2   4   6
3    3   6   9
4    4   8  12
5    5  10  15
6    6  12  18
7    7  14  21
8    8  16  24
9    9  18  27
10  10  20  30
``
```

Comment: could be an answer although - I cannot sort by column since real life values of my dataframe isint "sortable" as it is here. So if you know how to sort by index - please share the knowledge :)

Comment: You can use `sort_index` method to sort the index. Will give you the same output. Updated the answer.